# Get data attribute for selected dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to post a custom data attribute on a select box option to a hidden form field.

Here's my html:

```
<select id="sampleorder" multiple="multiple">
 <option value='xxx' data-amount='5'>Name</OPTION>
 <option value='xxx' data-amount='15'>Name</OPTION>
 <option value='xxx' data-amount='2'>Name</OPTION>
</select>
```

And jQuery

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
  var options = $('select#sampleorder');    
  var samplesSelected = options.val();

  $('input[name=order]').val(samplesSelected);
  $('input[name=quantity]').val(sampleAmount);
});
```

I'm guessing that my variable "sampleAmount" should look somewhat like this

```
  var sampleAmount = options.val().data("amount");
```

But it's not giving me the expected results.
What would be a good approach to get the data attribute value per item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
  var samplesSelected = $('#sampleorder').val(),
      sampleAmount = $('#sampleorder option:selected').data("amount");
  $('input[name=order]').val(samplesSelected);
  $('input[name=quantity]').val(sampleAmount);
});
```

Answer (score 16):

why use jQuery? Just use `event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.amount`

Comment: Thank you! I had to go through 4 different questions before I found an answer that didn't use jquery.

Comment: glad I could help:) haha I don't even remember writing this answer

Comment: Thanks! Found 8 jQuery solutions and only this one with vanilla javascript. In case someone else is looking for a way to get a data attribute of an option when it's selected, you need to set a variable with this, like so: `var yourVariable = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.your-data-attribute; });`. That would typically reside in a change Event Listener.

Comment: Why using jQuery? Because maybe to support IE <11 and still maybe to avoid mixing plain js method with jQuery one in case like OP where jq is used.

Answer (score 3):

In pure vanilla javascript you can use :

var sampleAmount = this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-amount'));

Example:

```js
function SelectChange(event) {
    console.log(event.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-amount')); 
}
```

```html
<select onchange="SelectChange(this)">
    <option data-amount="1">one</option>
    <option data-amount="2">two</option>
    <option data-amount="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This one should have gotten much more love than it has. Solution that works as is, with no jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**HTML**

Add id attribute to your `select drop down`
like

```
<select id="sampleorder" >
   ....
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 var sampleAmount = $('select#sampleorder option:selected').data("amount");
```

**Fiddle** http://fiddle.jshell.net/3gCKH/

Answer (score 1):

Another vanilla JS answer:

```
var selectContainer = document.getElementById('sampleorder')
var selectedOption  = selectContainer.selectedOptions.item()
var amount          = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-amount')
```

Comment: It should be `item(0)` I think

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention it has to be a multi select box, sorry.
With your help and a brief look into the jQuery documentation I've managed to solve it:

```
$("select#sampleorderm").change(function () {
    var samplesSelected = options.val().join("::");
    var samplesAmount = "";
        $("select#sampleorderm option:selected").each(function () {
            samplesAmount += $(this).data("amount") + " ";
        });

    $('input[name=sampleorder]').val(samplesSelected);
    $('input[name=sampleorderquantity]').val(samplesAmount);
 });
```